# Bitmap object absolute size is incorrect

Tags: android, bitmap, android-bitmap

I want to draw a circle with a 1 inch diameter, independent of the screen resolution, density, etc.  This seems to work on many of my test devices, but not on a Nexus 7.

```
Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(512,512, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bm);
//-- bm.getDensity() gives 213dpi for Nexus 7
//-- canvas.getDensity() gives 213dpi for Nexus 7
//-- so I set the radius to 213/2, so that the circle will be 1 inch

radiusPixels = bm.getDensity()/2f;
canvas.drawCircle(someX, someY, radiusPixels ,mPaint);
```

But this gives a circle about 5/8 inch on my Nexus 7, and exactly 1 inch on my Note 2.

I can also use

```
radiusPixels = getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.oneHalfInch); //-- <dimen name="oneHalfInch">0.5in</dimen>
canvas.drawCircle(someX, someY, radiusPixels ,mPaint);
```

and I get the same 5/8inch circle.

Any ideas?

Comment: why don't you use `in`: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension

Comment: you would think that would work, but it also fails, the circle is still about 5/8 inch instead of 1 inch